# How to send POST request from PHP to a service that is normally accessed using AJAX calls?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, post

Via asynchronous HTTP requests, I can use an existing service to load/save some information from/into a database. But these requests (AJAX) can be done, at least as far as I know, only from the client-side (e.g. a JavaScript script).

E.g. using jQuery *ajax* method:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: someurl,
    dataType: 'xml',
    data: xmlString, 
    success: function(data) { 
        // some code here 
    }
});
```

How can use the same service from a PHP script? That is, how can I "make an AJAX call from PHP", using either the POST or GET methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cURL library to access the same URL.

You will possibly need to set the "X-Requested-With" header to "XMLHttpRequest" in case the receiving service checks.

Otherwise, proceed as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928228/php-and-curl-get-ajax-data) except that you will be using the POST commented fields.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105358/curl-php-ajax-request) suggests how to debug and reverse engineer an existing AJAX service. Then, you will be able to use e.g. SimpleXML to decode the answer, which, from the jQuery code you posted, will come through in XML format.

**A TEST.**

```
$url = 'http://your-url';
$fields = array(
    'key' => 'value',
    // other fields
);
$headers = array(
    'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

// Note that you might have to set CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS to a urlification of
// $fields instead of an array, in case the service distinguishes form-data
// from url encoding.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, True);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

// IMPORTANT: some AJAX services will expect inbound data to be coming JSON encoded, so if that is the case, you shall have to write instead
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

$xml = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

print_r($xml);
```

Comment: @Iserni Thanks for the response, Iserni. What is the `$fields` array supposed to hold though?

Comment: You will place there whatever the original AJAX function was supposed to send. If it was attached to a form, then there would be all the form's fields (you may want to use Firebug as described in the link to verify field syntax and contents). If it was an ExtJS model you would send its columns. And that reminds me that I need to update the answer...

Comment: Curl is the good option but remember it's not asynchronous in the example above. You can check this question and answers if you want to make the calls asynchronous: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5453192/1712294

Comment: Good call, @MichalTrojanowski. Don't know it will be useful for the OP, but sure it is good to know for me!

Answer (score 1):

AJAX in PHP is not possible, but if you're talking about doing GET and POST to external sites, you will need libcurl

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

There's a lot of examples in there ;)